# EF Code-First Migrations doesn't allow to Share DB with same schema from two projects

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to share one database in two projects which has the same schema name.

Project 1 has few tables under "myschema". Project 2 also has few tables under "myschema". Assume that they don't have any shared tables to keep the scenario simple.

When I set up code first models and execute update-database for Project 1 it created all tables successfully, it created "myschema.__MigrationHistory" table. But when I try to do the update-database for project 2 it's giving me the error,

> There is already an object named '__MigrationHistory' in the database.

It's true, but I was under the impression that _MigrationHistory has ContextKey field which it can distinguish two projects. But it seems to be complaining upon table creation.

Has anyone came across this scenario trying to create tables for same schema from two projects?

Is this a limitation or is there any work around for this other that implementing different schema for Project 2?

If these projects have shared tables, will it throw the same error, which I believe that should be the case as per this observation.

[image]